# Hadoop returning less results than expected

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I have two python scripts a mapper and reducer (basically reducer at this point just prints nothing else) and while locally i get 4 results - strings
on hadoop i get 3. How does this work?

i use Amazon Elastic Map Reduce using Hadoop

mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
import os
# Constants declaration

WINDOW = 10
OVERLAP = 4
START_POSITION = 0
END_POSITION = 0

# regular expressions

pattern = re.compile("[a-z]*", re.IGNORECASE)

a_to_f_pattern = re.compile("[a-f]", re.IGNORECASE)
g_to_l_pattern = re.compile("[g-l]", re.IGNORECASE)
m_to_r_pattern = re.compile("[m-r]", re.IGNORECASE)
s_to_z_pattern = re.compile("[s-z]", re.IGNORECASE)

# variables initialization

converted_word = ""
next_word = ""
new_character = ""
filename = ""
prev_filename = ""
i = 0



# Read pairs as lines of input from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:

    line.strip()

    filename = os.environ['mapreduce_map_input_file']
    filename = filename.replace("s3://source123/input/","")


    # check if its a new file, and reset start position
    if filename != prev_filename:

        START_POSITION = 0
        next_word = ""
        converted_word = ""
        prev_filename = filename

    # loop through every word that matches the pattern
    for word in pattern.findall(line):


                new_character = convert(word)
                converted_word = converted_word + new_character

                if len(converted_word) > (WINDOW - OVERLAP):
                    next_word = next_word + new_character

                # print "word= ", word
                # print "converted_word= ", converted_word
            else:

                END_POSITION = START_POSITION + (len(converted_word) - 1)

                print converted_word + "," + str(filename) + "," + str(START_POSITION) + "," + str(END_POSITION)

                START_POSITION = START_POSITION + (WINDOW - OVERLAP)
                new_character = convert(word)
                converted_word = next_word + new_character
```

log

```
2016-04-27 19:58:41,293 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem (main): Consistency disabled, using com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem as filesystem implementation
2016-04-27 19:58:41,512 INFO amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver (main): MetricsConfigRecord disabledInCluster: false instanceEngineCycleSec: 60 clusterEngineCycleSec: 60 disableClusterEngine: true maxMemoryMb: 3072 maxInstanceCount: 500 lastModified: 1461784308237 
2016-04-27 19:58:41,512 INFO amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver (main): Created MetricsSaver j-KCDMFZJGYO89:i-995f5a41:RunJar:16480 period:60 /mnt/var/em/raw/i-995f5a41_20160427_RunJar_16480_raw.bin
2016-04-27 19:58:43,477 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-38-52.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.38.52:8032
2016-04-27 19:58:43,673 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-38-52.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.38.52:8032
2016-04-27 19:58:44,156 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): Opening 's3://source123/mapper.py' for reading
2016-04-27 19:58:44,267 INFO amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver (main): Thread 1 created MetricsLockFreeSaver 1
2016-04-27 19:58:44,439 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): Opening 's3://source123/source_reducer.py' for reading
2016-04-27 19:58:44,628 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader (main): Loaded native gpl library
2016-04-27 19:58:44,630 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec (main): Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 426d94a07125cf9447bb0c2b336cf10b4c254375]
2016-04-27 19:58:45,046 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): listStatus s3://source123/input with recursive false
2016-04-27 19:58:45,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat (main): Total input paths to process : 1
2016-04-27 19:58:45,336 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): number of splits:9
2016-04-27 19:58:45,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): Submitting tokens for job: job_1461784297295_0004
2016-04-27 19:58:45,710 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl (main): Submitted application application_1461784297295_0004
2016-04-27 19:58:45,743 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): The url to track the job: http://ip-172-31-38-52.us-west-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1461784297295_0004/
2016-04-27 19:58:45,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Running job: job_1461784297295_0004
2016-04-27 19:58:53,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1461784297295_0004 running in uber mode : false
2016-04-27 19:58:53,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:11,063 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 11% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:14,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 22% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:16,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 33% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:18,106 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 56% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:19,114 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 67% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:26,159 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 78% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:29,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 89% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:30,184 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 0%
2016-04-27 19:59:32,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 33%
2016-04-27 19:59:34,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 67%
2016-04-27 19:59:38,228 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 100%
2016-04-27 19:59:40,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1461784297295_0004 completed successfully
2016-04-27 19:59:40,409 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Counters: 55
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=190
        FILE: Number of bytes written=1541379
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=873
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=9
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
        S3: Number of bytes read=864
        S3: Number of bytes written=130
        S3: Number of read operations=0
        S3: Number of large read operations=0
        S3: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Killed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=9
        Launched reduce tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=9
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=6351210
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=2449170
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=141138
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=27213
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=141138
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=27213
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=203238720
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=78373440
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=5
        Map output records=3
        Map output bytes=124
        Map output materialized bytes=562
        Input split bytes=873
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=3
        Reduce shuffle bytes=562
        Reduce input records=3
        Reduce output records=6
        Spilled Records=6
        Shuffled Maps =27
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=27
        GC time elapsed (ms)=2785
        CPU time spent (ms)=11670
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=5282500608
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=28472725504
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=5977407488
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=864
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=130
2016-04-27 19:59:40,409 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob (main): Output directory: s3://source123/output/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapper task converts its inputs into lines and feed the lines to the stdin of the process.

In this case, you have *multiple* input files and you're *assuming* that all the lines from different files are fed sequentially (i.e. file by file), but they are likely processed in *parallel*, so a mapper (getting a couple of input files) could be resetting its counters more than expected by a sequential distribution.

Comment: how can i adjust my script then?

Comment: a first idea could be to transform your `prev_filename` into a dictionary with filename as key and to test if dictionary has key...